# how to create xlarge land variation xml?

Tags: android

I can't seem to be able to create a xlarge land variation for tablets for instance.

When I create new XML variations, this option is not present and creating a land variation creates it for phones.

so right now I have :

filename.xml
filename(land).xml
filename(xlarge).xml

How may I have filename(xlarge-land).xml?

Comment: large, xlarge are deprecated now . You should use sw<N> dp notations now

Comment: what are those? i've never used them and how can they help me making a sort of responsive design? i've never made an app that works on both phone orientations + both tablet orientations

Comment: Check the link Zoombie provided. You can also proceed in the way you are doing but should use updated things. Also sw from the above means screen width

Comment: I think I will do the way zoombie told, but should I create the folders manually or is there a way to create them via android studio? I don't wanna risk to break my xmls by doing something wron manually..

Comment: you have to create them manually

Answer (score 1):

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml              // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml        // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml       // layout for extra-large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml  // layout for extra-large in landscape orientation
```

reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers

Comment: thanks, should I create theese myself or is there a way to do it with android studio that could prevent errors or modifying manually the manifest?

Comment: Not sure about android studio generating folder structure automatically on modifying manifest.xml, but its rather easy to create such folder structure manually as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need create folder in res like this res/layout-large and then add filename.xml
to this floder

floder name:
layout-xlarge
layout-land